# How to prevent Facebook Pixel to track the same transaction twice?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-analytics, facebook-pixel

In my Purchase confirmation page, I send the purchase info to Facebook. But if my user hits Refresh, the data is sent again and Facebook compile the purchase values twice.

With Google Analytics, we can send a Transaction ID and even if the user refresh the page, the data is compiled only once.

Is there a way to achieve the same thing with Facebook? I would prefer to let Facebook do the job instead of having a flag on my side to send the Pixel only once.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using sessions. Before you render purchase page you can set some session flag which trigger rendering FB pixel code (or whatever) => after rendering this code you can remove this session. When your customer refresh page session is not set so your FB pixel code not rendered twice.

I used this idea in my extension for Nette Framework:
[Eflyax/facebook-pixel](https://github.com/Eflyax/facebook-pixel)

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking for a similar feature to Google Analytics's `Transaction ID` to deduplicate events.

So it turns out that Facebook does have such a parameter. Facebook calls it the `eventID` and it's used like this:

`fbq('track', 'Purchase', {value: 12, currency: 'USD'}, {eventID: 'EVENT_ID'});`

You can find the documentation of this parameter here: [Facebook docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/conversions-api/deduplicate-pixel-and-server-events/)